# How to reset scroll and section header in sectionList?

Tags: react-native, frontend, react-native-sectionlist

I am using sectionList to create sections for my application. I have two tabs which uses the same section list. The issue that I am facing is that when I click the second tab the data refreshes but the other properties like scroll position doesn't because sectionList is a pure component. This causes the header of the second section to disappear after scrolling to some point because there are lesser headers. The things I tried but did not provide any results are:

1. Use extraData to indicate re-render required
2. Cloning entire data